# safari and multiple large <img> tags (transparent png's) causing huge slowdown

Tags: html, css, performance, safari

I am working on a site where it has to be somewhat dynamically resizable and has multi-layered "twinkling lights" in the background. In chrome and firefox performance is negligible as I fade in and out the objects in a semi-random pattern but under safari their mere presence causes everything else to chug.

An example is this :

```
<div class="light_layer">
    <img class="lights" src="1.png" width="1400" alt="">
    <img class="lights" src="2.png" width="1400" alt="">
    <img class="lights" src="3.png" width="1400" alt="">
    <img class="lights" src="4.png" width="1400" alt="">
    <img class="lights" src="5.png" width="1400" alt="">
    <img class="lights" src="6.png" width="1400" alt="">
    <img class="lights" src="7.png" width="1400" alt="">
    <img class="lights" src="8.png" width="1400" alt="">
    <img class="lights" src="9.png" width="1400" alt="">
    <img class="lights" src="10-blue.png" width="1400" alt="">
    <img class="lights" src="10.png" width="1400" alt="">
    <img class="lights" src="11.png" width="1400" alt="">
    <img class="lights" src="12.png" width="1400" alt="">
    <img class="lights" src="13.png" width="1400" alt="">
    <img class="lights" src="14.png" width="1400" alt="">
    <img class="lights" src="15.png" width="1400" alt="">
    <img class="lights" src="16.png" width="1400" alt="">
    <img class="lights" src="17.png" width="1400" alt="">
    <img class="lights" src="18.png" width="1400" alt="">
    <img class="lights" src="19.png" width="1400" alt="">
</div>
```

The css :

```
.light_layer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.light_layer img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1200px;
    min-height: 677px;
}
```

At first I thought it was the fading that slowing things down but even when I stop all actions going on and just have the layers and goto mouseover a nav element there is serious slowdown. Delete the light layer and the slowdown is gone.

Paint calls in the safari inspector profiler are taking 750+ms. My question is how the hell can I reduce this performance chug while keeping their sizes to fit as they are if possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of having 19 different large images, could you have a single star image that you replicate and/or move around, instead (like spriting)?

Comment: I would but the problem is they are all different sizes/colors and can be on the page simultaneusly

Comment: Didn't understand. Are you using images over eachother ? Using `z-indexes` ?

Comment: no z-indexing just imagine a very large area like 1400x787 ( the size of each image ) but only a small are of the image itself ( maybe a 50x50 section ) has any content to it the rest being transparent blank space. its many of those layered on top of eachother